# The package 'react-native-document-scanner-plugin' doesn't seem to be linked

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating a document scanner app on react native expo using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-scanner-plugin . I copied the basic examples code from the website and when I run it, I keep getting these errors and my screen is completely blank:

## The package 'react-native-document-scanner-plugin' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure:

## You have run 'pod install'

## You rebuilt the app after installing the package

## You are not using Expo managed workflow

And when I run 'pod-install', I get this error message:

## No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

When I search it up online, it says that expo doesn't allow manual linking. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin doesn't run in Expo Go. It works with Expo, and you can avoid manually changing iOS and Android files by following these steps.

```
npx expo install react-native-document-scanner-plugin
```

Add react-native-document-scanner-plugin to plugins in app.json or app.config.json.

```
{
  "name": "my expo app",
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-native-document-scanner-plugin",
      {
        "cameraPermission": "We need camera access, so you can scan documents"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and

```
npx expo prebuild
```

or

```
eas build
```